# php user id assignment not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, sqlite

I am trying to user create user group system like facebook but i have problem with user id assignment.

My database design for users table:

```
username

uid

password

email
```

My database design for group_user:

```
group_id

group_name

group_information

group_cover

uid_fk
```

In this way `uid_fk` is `uid` from users table. When user create group i want to assign `uid` to `uid_fk`

This is my PHP code:

**group_user.php**

```
<?php 
  class group_user 
  {

      public function Create_User_group($group_name,$group_information,$uid) 
      {
        $group_name= mysql_real_escape_string($group_name);
        $group_information= mysql_real_escape_string($group_information);
        $qu= mysql_query("SELECT group_id FROM group_users WHERE
                            group_name='$group_name'");
        if(mysql_num_rows($qu)==0)
        {

            $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO 
                            group_users(group_name, group_information, uid_fk)
                            VALUES('$group_name','$group_information','$uid')");
            $sqll   = mysql_query("SELECT group_id 
                                    FROM group_users 
                                    WHERE group_name='$group_name' 
                                        and uid_fk='$uid'");
            $row   = mysql_fetch_array($sqll);
            $group_id   = $row['group_id'];
            $group_query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO 
                            group_friends(group_f_one, group_f_two, role)
                            VALUES('$group_id','$group_id','me')");
            return $blog_id ;

      } else {
            return false;
      }
    }     
  }
?>
```

**create_group.php**

```
<?php
    include_once 'includes/db.php';
    include_once 'includes/group_user.php';
    //Create group
    $group_user = new group_user();
    $reg_error='';
    if($_POST['group_name'] && $_POST['group_information'] )
    {
        $group_name=$_POST['group_name'];
        $group_information=$_POST['group_information'];

        if (strlen($group_name)>0 && strlen($group_information)>0)
        {
            $regg=$group_user->Create_User_group($group_name,$group_information);

            if($regg)
            {
                $_SESSION['group_id']=$regg;
                header("Location:group.php");
            }
            else
            {
                $reg_error="<span class='registererror'>Group name Already exist.</span>";
            }

        }
    }
?>
```

The problem is, when user create group uid_fk is automatically '0' not `uid`. What can i do to solve this problem?

Comment: You are missing the third parameter on this line of code `$regg=$group_user->Create_User_group($group_name,$group_information);` which is the value that will be used in the INSERT as uid_fk

Comment: @RiggsFolly what about adding an answer so it may be accepted and the question then may be marked as answered?

Comment: You shouldn't use `mysql_` in this day and age. See http://www.phptherightway.com/#databases

Answer (score 1):

You have just forgotten to place the third parameter on your call to

```
// missing param 3
$regg=$group_user->Create_User_group($group_name,$group_information);
```

Should be

```
$regg=$group_user->Create_User_group($group_name,$group_information, $THE_UID_PARAM);
```